# How to disable Vue 2's transition on leave

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I am working on a Vue 2 app it makes use of Vue's transitions. Each transition has enter and leave animations I am trying to disable the leave animation as it does not work well in some cases.

I have:

```html
<transition name="slide-fade" :duration="{ enter: 1500, leave: 1 }">
  <section id="step1" v-if="step == 1">
    <!-- some html -->
  </section>
</transition>
```

there are four of those transitions. Also, I found this css online to hide the leave transition:

```css
.slide-fade-leave-active {
  display: none;
  animation-duration: 0ms;
  transition: none !important;
}
```

if the `display: none` is missing then the leave animation works incorrectly it basically animates in from the side and disappears halfway through the element, which is very bizarre.

At this stage, the leave animation is not shown but still takes extra time for the new enter animation to kick in and I want to get rid of this wait - I thought setting the leave duration to 0ms or 1ms would disable it but it does not.

Comment: Purely a CSS issue IMO. You can't really make a transition disappear (it's in the name: transition). Try to look for some hack on how to kill your transition's starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Vue `<transition>` doesn't use [animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation). It uses [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition).

So it's not `animation-duration`, but `transition-duration`:

```css
.slide-fade-leave-active {
  transition-duration: 0s;
}
```

If it still doesn't work, I suggest providing a *runnable* [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) where I could have a look at what you have and test alternatives.

**Note:** I'm not really sure what takes priority when you use both CSS and the duration directive (`:duration="{ leave: n }`) - my guess is the directive takes precedence.
You might want to remove the `leave` part from the directive.